# Flask - How to convert user entered time to server UTC time?

Tags: python, datetime, flask, timezone-offset

I'm working on a project that allows users to enter due dates on a task. Currently, all times are stored serverside as their UTC equivalency and I have a setting where users can enter their timezone. How do I convert from the user-entered date to the UTC date, without storing the time itself?

The block of code below gets the current UTC datetime, adds in the day offset (default due date from today's date), and then converts it to the user's timezone so it is already selected on the front end.

```
date_offset = datetime.utcnow() + timedelta(days=int(current_user.get_setting('due_date_offset'))) form.due_date.data = date_offset.astimezone(timezone(current_user.get_setting('timezone')))
```

When the form is submitted, it is then converted back to the UTC time at the beginning of the day.

```
aware_due_date = datetime.combine(form.due_date.data, datetime.min.time()).replace(tzinfo=timezone(current_user.get_setting('timezone')))
        timezone_adjusted_due_date = aware_due_date.astimezone(timezone('UTC')).date()
```

My problem is that when the timestamp is rendered (via Flask-Moment) it is often a different day than the one intended. For example, if today is Sep. 26 UTC, and this is Sep. 27 in the user's timezone, it gets displayed properly on the user's date picker. When this is converted back to the UTC time, it is once again Sep. 26 at 00:00 (12:00 am), however, when this is finally rendered out, it may be displayed as Sep. 25.

Comment: If you're only interested in the date, then only work with dates, not with datetimes. Timezones are irrelevant to dates; Sept 26th is Sept 26th in Tokyo the same as in New York.

Comment: As soon as you add a time to your due date however (say 12 pm on Sept 26th Tokyo time), the dates-only strategy doesn't work anymore. Then you would have to work with aware datetime exclusively. Also note: [avoid utcnow](https://blog.ganssle.io/articles/2019/11/utcnow.html); instead, use `datetime.now(timezone.utc)`.

Comment: How do I get around the issue of the dates being wrong when first displayed to the user? For example, I've noticed that it can actually be the 27th, but on the calendar, the next day will be selected by default (safari seems to use the UTC time regardless of user timezone as well but not my concern). Between 10:00 and 11:00 UTC, there are three different dates being used across the world.